# up by 6% over ANY previous year?

Tags: expressions, comparatives

What does this "up by 6% over any previous year"?

Since 2019, Clarksville-Montgomery County has added over 6,000 new jobs and, even with the decline in travel from the pandemic, in the last 12 months hotel revenue is up by 6% over any previous year.
https://clarksvillenow.com/local/clarksville-montgomery-county-small-town-feel-with-big-potential/

I posted the same question at another bulletin board, but I still don't get it, so let me post it here again and ask for other people's opinions, please.

Does this mean "6% higher than the previous highest year"?

I found the same sentence structure in another news site.

Milholland said last year all three markets brought in a total of $1.3 million in sales, an increase of 11 percent over any previous year.
https://www.peninsuladailynews.com/news/port-townsend-saturday-market-to-open-for-the-season/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We may first reasonably assume that past revenue varied from year to year.

Arithmetically, the rise this year therefore cannot be 6% of *each* previous year. The sentence implies that it is 6% of *any* previous year.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any)
>
> Any:
> one of or each of, or a stated amount of (something that is more than one or has a number of parts), without saying which particular part is meant

So which part (year) is meant in your example?

- If the author had said “6% or more”, you would know arithmetically for sure that the 6% applied to the year with the highest revenue.  The % increase for other years would be higher than 6.
- If they had said “6% or less” you would know it applied to the lowest revenue year. The % increase for other years would be lower than 6.

The omission of *more* or *less* is at the root of your problem. Conventionally, and so as to avoid exaggerated statement that would come by comparing with the lowest revenue year, we understand the sentence to be setting a lower limit on the percentage rise, that is to understand it as “6% or more” and therefore the 6% to apply to the year that had the highest revenue.

I have analyzed it in my answer only so as to justify my understanding to you. But as a native speaker I would simply and instantly understand it as you suggest: "6% higher than (revenue in) the previous highest year" or "... the highest previous year".

Comment: Thank you, Anton and jsw29. Your interpretation was quite clear. But what confuses me is native speakers have quite different interpretation of this phrase. Is this expression rare?   Dou think this sentence structure is acceptable as decent English or marginally acceptable or incorrect?

Comment: @Kosuke Thanks. I have added to the answer so as to conclude with a more direct reply.

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

It's an infelicity. *Up by 6%...* suggests an increase from the year before, but the comparison brings in all previous years, without specifying whether there have been increases and decreases in the comparison base.

If all previous years are included in the comparison, it should be expressed as
*...6% higher than in any previous year.* or *... 6% higher than ever before*.

Comment: Thank you, Jack O'Flaherty.

Comment: What do you think the writer meant? Is it the same as "up by 6% than the previous year and this big increase is the highest increase of all the previous years"?

Comment: @Kosuke The likeliest meaning is what I suggested above - 6% higher than the corresponding figure in any previous year. Your suggestion, *...6% higher than the previous highest year* is equivalent to *6% higher than any prior year.*

Comment: If they meant that the 6% increase was greater than any previous annual increase, they really need to find better words to say it.

Comment: Thank you, Jack. I totally agree with your interpretation. The "higher than the previous highest year" interpretation was not mine, but by another native speaker.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, Kosuke.